# Erro ao usar atibuto "log" da anotação @Slf4j seguindo o tutorial do Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, log, slf4j

Estou estudando criação de APIs REST com Spring Boot seguindo o seguinte tutorial: [Building REST services with Spring](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/rest/).

Porem ao implementar ao classe **LoadDatabase** do tutorial estou recebendo recebendo um erro de compilação ao atualizar o atributo **log**, mesmo com o método estando com a anotação **@Slf4j**.

NOTA: Projeto criado no [Spring Iniializr](https://start.spring.io/), código escrito usando Eclipse, e executado com Maven por linha de comando usando `./mvnw spring-boot:run`.

Esta é a classe **LoadDatabase**

```java
package com.ricardo.studySpring.loaders;

import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import com.ricardo.studySpring.entities.Product;
import com.ricardo.studySpring.repotories.ProductRepository;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@Configuration
@Slf4j
public class LoadDatabase {

    @Bean
     public CommandLineRunner initDatabase(ProductRepository repository) {
        return args -> {
                log.info("Preloading " + repository.save(new Product("Banan", 2.25)));
                log.info("Preloading " + repository.save(new Product("carne", 20.0)));
        };
    }
}
```

Este é o arquivo **pom.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.8.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.ricardo</groupId>
    <artifactId>studySpring</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>studySpring</name>
    <description>Study of Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Este é o log de saída Maven

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  9.724 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-10-02T21:01:14-03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.1.8.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project studySpring: An exception occurred while running. null: InvocationTargetException: Error creating bean with name 'loadDatabase' defined in file [/home/ricardo/workspaces/projws-backend/studySpring/target/classes/com/ricardo/studySpring/loaders/LoadDatabase.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.ricardo.studySpring.loaders.LoadDatabase$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$42d56eee]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
[ERROR]     log cannot be resolved
[ERROR]     log cannot be resolved
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Comment: Você instalou o Lombok na sua IDE?

Comment: Bem, não. Eu estava usando IDE apenas como editor de texto e as vezes uso o Vim. Estou compilando e executando usando maven com o arquivo MVNW que vem no projeto gerado pelo start.spring.io.
Eu instalei e funcionou, mesmo quando executo usando o comando `./mvnw spring-boot:run` , mas apenas quando o código é escrito usando a IDE com o plugin. O estranho é que não tinha nenhum problema com a anotação `@Data` quando estava escrevendo código sem instalar.
Eu vou atualizar a pergunta. Pode escrever a resposta para eu marcar, mas se possível seria legal explicar o porque isso acontece.

Comment: Nesse meio tempo você não fez nenhuma alteração de dependências (explicitou dependência de log por exemplo)?

Comment: Não, está tudo igual ao tutorial. A única coisa que cheguei a tentar depois que você escreveu o primeiro comentário foi adicionar `<scope>provided</scope>` na dependência do Lombok do pom.xml, mas não fez diferença. Fiquei pesquisando sobre Lombok nesse meio tempo, em todos os lugares mandam instalar o lombok em um IDE, só não tenho certeza se é só para que o auto-corretor da IDE consiga trabalhar adequadamente ou se a ferramenta de build(no meu caso, o maven) precisa que ele esteja instalando em uma IDE para trabalhar adequadamente.

Comment: Contudo, acho que isso foge do escopo da pergunta. Pode escreve a resposta e eu irei marca como aceita. Se conseguir explicar o porque isso acontece será ótimo, deixará a resposta mais rica. Caso contrario não tem problema, ainda soluciona a questão e posteriormente irei abrir outra pergunta para tratar especificamente da questão da obrigatoriedade de instalar o Lombok em uma IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conforme sugerido no comentário, realizar a [instalação](https://projectlombok.org/setup/eclipse) do Lombok em sua IDE deve resolver o problema.

Mas por curiosidade, para saber o porque realizar essa ação de fato resolve o problema dei uma olhada em como o Lombok de fato funciona *under the hood*.

O processamento de anotações do Lombok é realizado utilizando a [JSR 269: Pluggable Annotation Processing API](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=269).

Ao realizar a instalação do Lombok, o seguinte caminho é incluído no classpath: `/META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor`. Durante a compilação utilizando o `javac`, as anotações são interpretadas de acordo.

> **2.7 Please give a short description of the underlying technology or technologies:** In order to realize the full benefits of annotations, a
>   standardized mechanism is necessary to process them in contexts other
>   than a running jvm. Since annotations are added to declarations
>   (classes, methods, fields, etc.), the API needs to include a model of
>   program structure. Additionally, the processors for different
>   annotations should be able to work cooperatively and the set of
>   processors that are run should be able to depend on what annotations
>   are present in the code being processed.
>
> **2.8 Is there a proposed package name for the API Specification? (i.e., javapi.something, org.something, etc.)** All the API elements are
>   expected to reside in the javax namespace; the language modeling
>   portions of the API might be called javax.mirror.declaration,
>   javax.mirror.type, etc. while the processing related portions of the
>   API might be called **javax.annotation.processing.**